# Assign JSON as a property

Tags: javascript, css, json

I have the following method in my class:

```
/**
 * Loops through a JSON object and assigns the styles to the element
 */
this._assignClass = (function (className, element) {
    for (var styleName in className) {
        if (className.hasOwnProperty(styleName)) {

            var style = element.style;

            // *** THIS LINE IS NOT CORRECT ***
            style.styleName = className[styleName];

        }
    }
});
```

and the following JSON object:

```
this.configuration = {
    class: {
        arrowUp: {
            width: "0px",
            height: "0px",
            borderLeft: "10px solid transparent",
            borderRight: "10px solid transparent",
            borderBottom: "10px solid black"
        }
    }
};
```

I am calling the method like so:

```
this._assignClass(this.configuration.class.arrowUp, someDivElement);
```

The method is supposed to take the JSON object and assign all the styles to the element from the object in this case `this.configuration.class.arrowUp`.  The problem I'm having is that `style.styleName` is being interpreted incorrectly.  How do I pass the correct value to `style` ?

Comment: `height: "0px",` not `height: "0px"` - missing a comma

Comment: @jdphenix, I fixed that error. The stated problem still persists.

Comment: Dang - you always hope it's something simple :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this._assignClass = (function (className, element) {
    for (var styleName in className) {
        if (className.hasOwnProperty(styleName)) {

            var style = element.style;

            // *** TRY THIS ONE ***
            style[styleName] = className[styleName];

        }
    }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Style is just a object so you can assign its property using `[]`.

```
this._assignClass = (function (className, element) {
    for (var styleName in className) {
        if (className.hasOwnProperty(styleName)) {
            //simply this would work
            element.style[styleName] = className[styleName];
        }
    }
});
```